# Floating elements in css

Tags: css, css-float

On this website
http://inspectelement.com/html5portfolio/
, I saw that he is using a `float:left;` command on the html5 `<header>` -element, and the css class "section", which is the area where the content is.

If I change it to `float:right`, or `float:none`, or I delete it altogether nothing changes.

Why is he using the float command anyway?

The header has a fixed position, and the section is centered through the container:

```
#headercontainer, #contentcontainer { 
    width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; 
}
```

Is this some sort of technique, I´m not familiar with? Or can I just delete the float command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you stealing his markup/css?

Comment: @b_dubb That page is actually a demo from [an HTML5 tutorial](http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/code-a-backwards-compatible-one-page-portfolio-with-html5-and-css3/) on the site, so I'd guess the author wouldn't feel too bad about it being "stolen"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probably uses floats so the element get's out of normal flow and he is not clearing them to keep the bottom margin+section height at a state of 1000px no matter how much content is in the floated section. However if `<section>` content will get over 1000px his approach will break. But since it's a portfolio site he will manage to keep it working.

Answer (score 0):

The `float: left` declaration on the `.section` class is actually overridden by the parent `#contentcontainer` element which has `float: none` so you're quite right - it's not doing anything at all!

Comment: #contentcontainer is not overriding it. It just isn't floated - all the sections inside are still floated.

Comment: Yeah you're right - it's overriding the `float: left` declaration for itself, but not its children.

Answer (score 0):

i think he actually uses `float:left` to give his `<section>` elements the correct height. without the `float:left` the `<section>` elements take their height from the `<h2>`.

Use firebug to remove the `float:left` you'll notice the `<section>`s heights shrink.